# Comparing various NSStrings to one nsstring

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am creating a type of stopwatch app. Now to have it "Running" in the background I save the `NSDate` when the button is pressed and compare it to when the user comes back.

The point where i'm at now is using a popup asking to erase all the values if the timers aren't running. The timer saves a `NSString` to `NSUserDefaults` when it is pressed to indicate running vs not running. here is the code I have tried:

```
NSString *TS = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run"];
NSString *TS1 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run1"];
NSString *TS2 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run2"];
NSString *TS3 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run3"];
NSString *TS4 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run4"];
NSString *TS5 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run5"];
NSString *TS6 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run6"];
NSString *TS7 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run7"];
NSString *TS8 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run8"];
NSString *TS9 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run9"];
NSString *TS10 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run10"];
NSString *TS11 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run11"];
NSString *TS12 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run12"];
NSString *TS13 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run13"];
NSString *TS14 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run14"];
NSString *TS15 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run15"];
NSString *TS16 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run16"];
NSString *TS17 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run17"];
//   NSString *TS18 = [prefs objectForKey:@"Run18"];


if  ([TS   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS1   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] |[TS2   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] |[TS3   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS4   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] |[TS5   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS6   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS7   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS8   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS9   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS10   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] |[TS11   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS12   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] | [TS13   isEqual: @"NotRunning"] |[TS14   isEqual: @"NotRunning"]|[TS15   isEqual: @"NotRunning"]|[TS16   isEqual: @"NotRunning"]|[TS17   isEqual: @"NotRunning"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Would you like to clear everything?",@"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NO",@"") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"YES",@""), nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    alert.tag = 99;

    [alert show];
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated! so thanks in advance :)

Comment: Put them in a NSArray, then you can loop it to decide to show or not alert.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I need to have all of these equaling not running to show the alert though and if even one of them doesn't equal not running then to not show the alert. if this makes any sense  @Larme

Comment: @user3775028 I've adjusted my answer to your latest comment. Please remember to give feedback if an answer doesn't work, or mark your problem as solved if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL allNotRunning = YES;
for(int index = 1;index < 19; index++){
    NSString *key = index == 1 ? "Run" : [NSString stringWithFormat:"Run%d", index];
    if(![[prefs objectForKey:key] isEqualToString:@"NotRunning"]){allNotRunning = NO;}
}

if(allNotRunning){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Would you like to clear everything?",@"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NO",@"") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"YES",@""), nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    alert.tag = 99;

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: `allNotRunning` should probably be named `allRunning`.

Comment: That loop which calculates the `allNotRunning` flag is nonsense: You are testing each element of a set for being equal to one specific value—yet sets are build for efficient lookup of one specific value. The flag can be calculated efficiently and concise: `allRunning = [stringSet member:@"NotRunning"] == nil;`

Comment: You don't need the set at all when you calculate the condition in the first loop.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. You're totally right. On second thought I'd use `allRunning = [stringSet containsObject:@"NotRunning"]` so I can remove the == nil check. I'll correct my answer